# Function to return table of a number

Tags: python

I have tried below code to return a multiplication table for input number:

```
def table_of(n):
    for i in range(1,11):
        print(n,"*",i,"=",n*i)
a = input("Enter a Number:")
table_of(a)
```

This returns:

```
Enter a Number:2
2 * 1 = 2
2 * 2 = 22
2 * 3 = 222
2 * 4 = 2222
2 * 5 = 22222
2 * 6 = 222222
2 * 7 = 2222222
2 * 8 = 22222222
2 * 9 = 222222222
2 * 10 = 2222222222
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Need: `a = int(input("Enter a Number:"))` (i.e. convert to int since input is a string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `input()` function returns a string therefor the loop prints that string i times. The solution would be to replace `a = input(“Enter a number: ”)` with

`a = int(input(“Enter a number: ”))`

Answer (score 2):

The output from an input statement is always a string. You need to convert `n` to an integer before multiplying, either at the `input` statement, or in the `print`, as below.

```
def table_of(n):
    for i in range(1,11):
        print(n,"*",i,"=",int(n)*i)
a = input("Enter a Number:")
table_of(a)
```

Gives the output:

```
Enter a Number:>? 2
2 * 1 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
2 * 3 = 6
2 * 4 = 8
2 * 5 = 10
2 * 6 = 12
2 * 7 = 14
2 * 8 = 16
2 * 9 = 18
2 * 10 = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a function to return a table of any number without using print inside a function:

```py
def table(x):
    for i in range(1,11):
        yield f'{x}*{i}={x*i}'
num = int(input("Enter a number : "))
a  = table(num)
for i in a:
    print(i)
```